# Dock is crashing 20.04

Tags: dock

sometimes during the workday my dock crashes and i can't use it anymore, needed to reboot or  logout.

Is it possible to fix it without reboot\logout the ubuntu?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the gnome-shell (which is responsible for the user interface).

You can do it quickly with the *Run a Command* dialog.

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for the dialog to open, type just `r` in the text-field, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>