# What is causing this Authentication Required prompt in 20.04.2

Tags: authentication, bug-reporting

I have this authentication required prompt that keeps coming up in a 20.04.2 install. I'm not sure which application or service is causing it to trigger but when I enter my password and press authenticate it goes away. Sometimes it comes back again and not knowing why it is showing up is frustrating. Another inconvenient behavior is that when I leave the computer and return it will sometimes be on the desktop but the "Cancel" and "Authenticate" buttons will not work so there is no apparent way to get rid of it besides rebooting my computer. It's like the process that created the dialog is no longer handling user input but the dialog is still present and in the way.

[image]

I believe this is my gs extensions:
[image]
Desktop Icon's by rastersoft appears to be the only one enabled?

```
james@james-NUC5i5MYHE:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
@as []
```

From my Logs program here are the important log messages that appear after launching:

```
12:39:24 PM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
12:39:12 PM bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
12:39:10 PM kernel: usb 2-4: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
12:39:08 PM bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
12:39:06 PM kernel: usb 2-4: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
12:39:05 PM systemd-udevd: /etc/udev/rules.d/79-scanner.rules:1 Invalid key/value pair, ignoring.
```

If someone can advise how to report and maybe disable this that would be helpful.

Comment: That dialog is weird even in its appearance: it's supposed to be on the very center of the screen, with a dark overlay behind it (that cannot be controlled by regular (gnome-shell-)themes). Your gnome-shell seems to have some hiccups. Please update your question with the list of gnome-shell-extensions that you have installed. In the meanwhile, for a quick workaround, try restarting the gnome-shell, like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1319534/1157519

Comment: It normally shows up in the center and operates in that I can cancel or enter my password and authenticate. The image is when I leave the computer alone for a while and come back to a non functional window oddly on the left side of the display.

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` Could you edit your question and add the return value of this command? Please put every item on a new line (you can force line breaks in the markdown editor by appending two dangling spaces at the end of the line where you want the break).

Comment: Also open the app called "Logs", and look on its first screen, called the _Important_ tab. Do you see anything telling in there?

Comment: @Levente updated with some of the requested info. The main customizations on this system is installing Master PDF Editor which I used to integrate a fujitsu scansnap, teamviewer, google chrome, skype

Comment: Ahh, it's written on the dialog: "Authentication is required **to refresh the system repositories**" I have found a few things when searching that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193810/authentication-required-to-refresh-system-repositories-in-ubuntu-19-10 and https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14051

Comment: Also this: https://github.com/TurboVNC/turbovnc/issues/207#issuecomment-594380904

Comment: @Levente, Thanks! I tried DeepSpace101's first answer and will report back if this resolves improves the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just resuming the workaround that worked for me, taken from some comments, thanks to Levente and the other contributors.

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It restarts the Gnome Shell, getting rid of the "ghost" popup.
In my case, all the other applications and windows didn't have any side effects.

Here's the link to the official bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1824874

Comment: Thanks for recognizing all the commentators.